# Are there additional structural measures in airliners with asymemtrical seating arrangements?

Tags: weight-and-balance, cg, configuration, seating-capacity

I was recently flying onboard an A220 and was surprised by the asymmetrical five abreast seating arrangement.

Are there any structural measures (e.g. counter weights, ...) to balance out the aircraft specifically because of the asymmetrical seating configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lateral center of gravity limits, mostly to deal with fuel imbalance and to deal with controllability and trim limits in a worst-case flight configuration,like an engine failure right after rotation.

A cabin load offset of a foot or so from center line, because the aisle was offset, has no significant structural impact and will have a trim impact (roll tendency) that is negligible, compared to other effects like fuel imbalance. In fact you can have certain amount of variability in roll trim from airplane to airplane just from variations in symmetry of the wing structure (twist). Everything has tolerances.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation.